# onSensorChanged function is called in an other app but not in mine (Kotlin)

Tags: kotlin, android-sensors

i want to implement a step counter in my app, so i search how to make that and i found lot of differents implementations.

I notably found an app on GitHub which works. I have tried to implement this code in my app and in an other "test" app but any of them works and i don't no why.

The problem is caused by the onSensorChanged function of my STEP_COUNTER which is not called.

I have search in all the files of the app and i don't found the problem.

If somebody have a solution...

(I'm french so sorry if it's badly written)

Comment: Provide the code you have used. Are you requesting permissions to read the sensor? Have you stated your `<uses-permission>` `<uses-hardware>` in your `AndroidManifest.xml`?

Comment: Yes i have state <uses-permission> but not the <uses-hardware>

Answer (score 0):

the code i use:

```
private var sensorManager: SensorManager? = null

    // Creating a variable which will give the running status
    // and initially given the boolean value as false
    private var running = false

    // Creating a variable which will counts total steps
    // and it has been given the value of 0 float
    private var totalSteps = 0f

    // Creating a variable  which counts previous total
    // steps and it has also been given the value of 0 float
    private var previousTotalSteps = 0f

//in the onCreate

loadData()
        resetSteps()

        // Adding a context of SENSOR_SERVICE as Sensor Manager
        sensorManager = getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE) as SensorManager

override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        mainHandler.post(pingRunnable)
        binding.map.onResume()

        running = true

        // Returns the number of steps taken by the user since the last reboot while activated
        // This sensor requires permission android.permission.ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION.
        // So don't forget to add the following permission in AndroidManifest.xml present in manifest folder of the app.
        val stepSensor = sensorManager?.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_STEP_COUNTER)


        if (stepSensor == null) {
            // This will give a toast message to the user if there is no sensor in the device
            Toast.makeText(this, "No sensor detected on this device", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        } else {
            // Rate suitable for the user interface
            sensorManager?.registerListener(this, stepSensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_UI)
        }
    }

    override fun onSensorChanged(event: SensorEvent?) {

        // Calling the TextView that we made in activity_main.xml
        // by the id given to that TextView
        var tvStepsTaken = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.step)

        if (running) {
            totalSteps = event!!.values[0]

            // Current steps are calculated by taking the difference of total steps
            // and previous steps
            val currentSteps = totalSteps.toInt() - previousTotalSteps.toInt()

            // It will show the current steps to the user
            tvStepsTaken.text = ("$currentSteps")
        }
    }

    private fun resetSteps() {
        var resetButton = findViewById<Button>(R.id.reset)
        resetButton.setOnClickListener {
            // This will give a toast message if the user want to reset the steps
            previousTotalSteps = totalSteps

            // When the user will click long tap on the screen,
            // the steps will be reset to 0
            testFragment?.binding?.step?.text = 0.toString()

            // This will save the data
            saveData()

            true
        }
    }

    private fun saveData() {

        // Shared Preferences will allow us to save
        // and retrieve data in the form of key,value pair.
        // In this function we will save data
        val sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("myPrefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)

        val editor = sharedPreferences.edit()
        editor.putFloat("key1", previousTotalSteps)
        editor.apply()
    }

    private fun loadData() {

        // In this function we will retrieve data
        val sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("myPrefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
        val savedNumber = sharedPreferences.getFloat("key1", 0f)

        // Log.d is used for debugging purposes
        Log.d("MainActivity", "$savedNumber")

        previousTotalSteps = savedNumber
    }

    override fun onAccuracyChanged(sensor: Sensor?, accuracy: Int) {
        // We do not have to write anything in this function for this app
    }
```